# What are ROS projects to practice?

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am using ROS on and off on average every 6 months.
To stay active however, I would like to do more projects in ROS and do more advanced stuff (since I always go back after a long break, I most often do rudimentary IPC things, not much with RVIZ, etc.).

So I wanted to know if you guys can recommend ROS projects that one can do to practice.
Something like these projects of this upcoming course: https://www.udacity.com/course/robotics-nanodegree--nd209
But without grading and free.
Basically I am looking for advanced tutorials beyond what the wiki offers or something like the Kaggle challenges for ROS.

I wouldn't even be opposed if you can refer me to a book that contains this. But I think all the ROS books around are either obsolete and/or very basic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260609/what-are-ros-projects-to-practice?/) by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a real answer, but frankly speaking: get yourself a robot and try to do something cool with it! ;-)

No really, i think at some point it does not make sense to make the Tutorials more and more advanced. If you reached that point maybe it is time to get your hands dirty on real (or Student) robotics Projects. You will see that there is a Lot of Advanced stuff behind the Tutorials and Brooks.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1